# Remote Lazy Loading in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Normally web applications having access to hibernate session use lazy loading to fetch parent entity with multiple child entities. But in case of distributed application where the presentation layer doesn't have access to hibernate session, how will lazy loading happen (remotely)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how will lazy loading happen (remotely)?

It won't, Hibernate does not support this out-of-the-box (for a reason, but see [this](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RemoteLazyLoading) for instance).

Your only option is to eagerly fetch everything you want (which is considered a good practice anyway) or explicitly ask for lazy collections on remote side (by calling the "Hibernate" side again).

Comment: Ok so eager fetch is the only option but then what about the performance? Loading everything up in cases where parent has got multiple children (for instance 3 or 4 levels in a tree or considerably huge amount of data) might freak my boss out of his seat.

Comment: If you have *tree-like* structure in the database that you display on some GUI remotely you should implement lazy-loading yourself by asking the server explicitly for children of a given node when it is accessed. In fact it's much simpler than to rely on Hibernate.